# popping noise on 07 charger

Tags: brakes, charger

So my car a while now has been making a popping noise and it's gotten worse. Everytime I step on the brake something from the bottom of my car pops most of the time when I turn the steering wheel it pops. Does anybody know what it might be :/

Comment: 4 close votes but not a single user, posted a comment asking for more information. We have been quick to close questions like this without providing any feedback to the OP on what we need in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popping could be from a ball joint or a tierod end. Both of these items are a serious safety concern. If either fails completely you will loose control of the car. Any noise or looseness in the front of the car should be investigated immediately.